# How to convert ListBuffer to List (immutable collection ) in scala

Tags: list, scala

I have the below code using ListBuffer but I want to use immutable collection like List and achieve the same result

```
val list1: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer("a", "b", "c")
val s= list1
    .foldLeft(mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]) { (strings, content) =>
      {
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(content))
          strings += content
        else
          strings += "-"

      }
    }
    .mkString(";")
```

Second version

```
val list1: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer("a", "b", "c")
val s= list1
    .foldLeft(mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]) { (strings, content) =>
      {

       strings += content

      }
    }
    .mkString(";")
```

Comment: .toList? should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect`

```scala
  List("a", "b", "c").collect {
    case c if StringUtils.isNotBlank(c) => c
    case _ => "-"
  }.mkString(";")
```

Comment: In case I do  not have a blank value check , is there any alternative to collect

Comment: if you don't do any checks, there is no point in `foldLeft `, this will be sufficient `List("a", "b", "c").mkString(";")`

Comment: Since you never drop any elements, I think `map` instead of `collect` will suffice here.